# Failed to create database 'metastore_db', see the next exception for details

Tags: hive

I'm getting the following exception while trying to start the `hive` in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS,`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to create database 'metastore_db', see the next exception for details.` Hadoop installation is correct and it's working fine. Please tell me anyone what's problem?

Comment: Paste your hive-site.xml

Comment: Also, paste the next exception. Also, check that you have write permission in the directory where you launched hive. In the default installation hive uses Derby as database, which also by default will create the metastore in the current directory.

Comment: http://www.edureka.co/blog/apache-hive-installation-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I'm sorry but i followed the above link for hive installation. It has no instructions  regarding `hive-site.xml`. But it was working pretty well though.I could run hive from command prompt.But now im getting that error. I dont know what went missing.

Comment: @RobertoCongiu yes that was the problem sir i got it. I was trying to launch hive from outside hduser directory. I guess i have to configure the `hive-site.xml` to be able to run hive from anywhere. Thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 7):

It is because you're not in the same folder where you have created your metadata. I was facing the same problem because I was in my main user folder. When  I changed the folder from main user to hduser my hive stated working.
See [the mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjMCI.png) 
I tried to find the xml file but it was not their so I searched and found where it was.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @dk14, In my case, I was in a folder on which I had no permission to write as user, moved directory and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for above error is, the user through which you are login doesn't have permission to write in that particular directory. I mean the directory in which you are running the schematool command.

For example my setup of Apache Hive was in /opt/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin I ran the command :-
sudo chown -R hadoopusr /opt/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is happening because you are on the other folder than your hive is installed.
so first of all change directory to the folder where your hive is installed and you and after that try to run hive once again.
and the hive should work properly.
Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some(lot) of time I got that issue is with creating that directory `metastore_db` inside `DERBY_HOME/bin` path was already there and I didn't had admin access for this you either:

1. delete that folder by using admin rights.
2. open `hive-site.xml` inside `HIVE_HOME/conf` path `open` in `notepad` and check `connection string` there change the database name to something else, it worked for me.